# using python activate my webcam and detect faces

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

using opencv2, I tried to detect the human faces from webcam using the below code:-

```
  import cv2

  import sys

  cascPath = sys.argv[1]

  faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

  video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

  while True:

  ret, frame = video_capture.read() 

  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.1,minNeighbors=5,
  minSize=(30, 30), flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE)

  for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

  cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

  cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

  break

  video_capture.release()

  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am unable to execute the complete code as i got an error at the below step:-

```
 ret, frame = video_capture.read() //error msg **expected an intended block**
```

Thanks,
breeze

Comment: Have you tried indenting the block?

Answer (score 2):

Indenting is very important in Python, it forms the structure of the code. Your script would need to be indented something like as follows:

```
import cv2
import sys

cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read() 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1,
                minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30), 
                flags= cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To run this script for face recognition:

```
python myscript.py C:\opencv\build\etc\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
```

Comment: You would need to start your script from the command line, e.g. `python myscript.py haarcascade_filename.xml` where `myscript.py` is the filename of your script, and `haarcascade_filename.xml` is the filename of the CascadeClassifier that you are using from your OpenCV folder.

Comment: Thanks martin... i changed the line as u suggested...  the error i got is flags= cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE)
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'cv'

Comment: I made the line flags= 0  then the error i am getting is invalid syntax  at the line for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

Comment: Try taking the `.cv` out, e..g `cv2.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE`. This depends on the version of OpenCV you are using.

Comment: For later versions use: `flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE`

Comment: my opencv version is 3.1.0  and python vers is 3.6.0a2   i tried by changing the loop as for faces in [x, y, w, h]:   same issue is persisting. needyur help martin